# Is a comparative title in an ongoing book series considered a recent comp or not?

Tags: titles, agent, queries

I have a novel where I have an excellent comparative ("comp") title in mind, but the book is part of an ongoing series of novels (scifi/fantasy, if it matters). The suggested time range for a comp title is 3-5 years, and there has been a book in the series published within that time frame. I've seen only oblique references to the issue if the comp title counts, with somewhat conflicting advice. Is the comp title considered "current" because of the ongoing series, or is it out-of-date because the original book in the series was published over 20 years ago? Is it only current if I reference the very latest book in the series?

I could supply more specifics if needed, but I'm interested in the more general question since I've read a LOT of books in series that are still being published.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what you are talking about. What is a 'comp'? (I realise this is an adjective but I don't know what it refers to.)

Comment: @S.Mitchell A comp title is a similar book that could be compared with yours (I think). I also think comp is short for comparative hence the OP's title: Is a **comparative title** in an ongoing book series considered a recent comp or not?

Comment: @S. Mitchell Yes, comp is shorthand for "comparative title," a book similar to yours that gives agents a frame of reference for what your book is similar to. Ideally, a comp is recent, so the agent knows you are in touch with what is currently selling. I've read so many older books that are in series that I want to know if the older books with titles currently being published in the series are acceptable. But the perfect comp that dates you is not a comp at all. Ageist, but there's nothing to be done about it. I have more recent titles I can use, I just like the older one better.